# Is the use of preposition "with" being correctly used in this context?

Tags: prepositions

The headline is:

"Eva Mireles’s husband was an officer with the school district’s Police Department. He was not allowed to enter the place where his wife was under attack."

What caught my attention was, "an officer with the school district’s Police Department" part

Is "officer with the Police Department" correct?

The way it would make sense to my English-learning mind would be:

"officer IN the Police Department." It's a department and the officer is part of it, within it's scope.

OR

"officer OF the the Police Department." Again it's a department and the officer comes from it for being an officer of course.

But what is the pois of using "with"???

Comment: I've corrected your spelling and punctuation, but what is "pois" in the last line? Do you mean "point"?

Comment: There's not much point tagging both British and American English.

Comment: pois would be point, I'm sorry for this. I guess in this aspect brit and american English are the same, right?

Comment: Using "police department" marks these as coming from the USA, since that is US term  But the use of "with" can apply to both.

Answer (score 0):

Much prepostion use depends on idioms, and "officer with the police department" is idiomatic:  Here are some examples:

> [A] former officer with the police department in St. Louis recently wrote about his experience for The Washington Post:

> An applicant for employment as a Probationary Patrol Officer with the Police Department of the Village of Lincolnshire, Illinois,

> Inn is survived by his wife, who is also an officer with the police department, a seven-month-old baby and two stepchildren ages 12 and 14.

But you are right that "in the police department is also used:

> This is a non-exempt position as an entry level law enforcement officer in the Police Department.

> The success of an officer in the police department depends on best training, well-discipline, commitment to serve the humanity, ...

The use of "police department" marks all of these as American (the UK doesn't use "department" of divisions of the police).

There seems to be little difference in meaning between "in the police department" and "with the police department", but the with idiom can also apply to, for example soldiers

> an operations officer with the Household Cavalry Regiment, working on battle-planning.

Comment: I was thinking about it and came up with the idea that the "with" is being used because a department is a group and the office is "with" members of that group. Make any sense? I seek semantic in everything even in the syntax LOL. I belive even syntax deppends on logic.

Comment: Very little in language depends on logic  (except Logic, of course) This is really just idiom. My guess would be that the idiom developed first for officers "with" a regiment of soldiers, and then transferred to the police.

Comment: I miss the point here, how  "he" being in a soldier regimen first convey the "with" to phrase: with Police Department"???

Comment: @ James K, do you mean as though "he" is a soldier working "with" the police department?

Comment: when you say: "the officers are with the soldiers." you mean working together in the regiment right? So the "office with" would be a description of an office who work along with soldier, impplying this office also knows soldiers tatics? sorry for the confusion I'm making here.

Comment: The officers lead and give orders. But this is all irrelevant to the the question. However it developed the use of "officer with the police department" is idiomatic and correct, however illogical it is.

Comment: I will try to get  peace of mind with that LOL. The thing is when you say an office is "with" the soldier in regiment, I still can't see the point in carrying the "with" from with soldier to with in "with police department"

Comment: unless and it occurred to me now, you mean an office with soldiers in a regiment leading them, can also be in a police department leading a group or doing some other task. sorry my inssistence i get very frustated when don't get a subjet in its totality

Comment: No.  Nothing to do with "office" Only with "officer".  I'm sorry I mentioned anything, it was just because you wanted a "logical" reason.  And there is no logical reason.  But there might be a historical reason.

Comment: The Historical reason **might be**  1. There are officers and "non-officer soldiers"

Comment: Perhaps People used to say the non-officer soldiers are "in the regiment"

Comment: Perhaps People used to say the officers are with the regiment.

Comment: So the idiom might have become "John is an officer with the regiment".

Comment: Then when people started to talk about police they **might** say "John is an officer with the police department".

Comment: Now I'm soon going to delete all these comments, as they are **not relevant**.  They are not part of the totality of the subject.  They are just some random speculation.

Comment: I appretiate your time and effort in especulate about that after my nagging questions, may be irrelevant to main point but was very clarifying to me in sense that showed a little how a native english-speaking mind would think about that

Answer (score 0):

English offers flexibility in preposition choice when speaking of membership in an organization. Generally speaking, you can say you work **for** an organization, or work **at** an organization, without much difference in meaning. You can also say you are **in**, **with**, or **from** an organization, or that you are a member **of** that organization, or that you belong **to** the organization.

The precise circumstances of use will differ slightly. **With** often indicates a professional association. If you have a membership with an organization (such as a gym or church) but do not work there, it may be less appropriate to use **with**.